# Problem using PUN2 for a VR multiplayer experience in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, oculus, photon, oculusquest

I'm trying to create a simple VR demo where two users can connect to a room a manipulate objects on a table. I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/demos-and-tutorials/oculusavatarsdk).

I have followed it step-by-step:

- Duplicated `LocalAvatar` and `RemoteAvatar` prefabs and moved them to
  Resources

  Created the script `PhotonAvatarView` Script

  Attached and configured `PhotonAvarView` and `PhotonView` to both prefabs

The problem is that I get stuck at the "*Instantiate Avatars*" section, specifically at the section:

> The following code can be placed for example in your already existing
>   Network Manager or any other script that already deals with network
>   logic, it doesn't belong to the PhotonAvatarView script we created
>   earlier. Here we are using the OnJoinedRoom callback.

My assumption is that this is a tutorial from scratch (given the way it starts with a blank Unity project), but I don't have any Network Manager script in place so I'm a bit confused. Putting that code into a new script and just attaching it to an object doesn't seem working.

Am I missing some parts?

Comment: So... is your question *What is this thing that the tutorial refers to, but doesn't explain?*

Comment: The network manager is a singleton that you would usually have in your project to be the hub of your networking. If the tutorial doesn't explain it, or at least give you a demo one, then you probably want to try another tutorial.

Comment: Hi Claus, the link to the tutorial you mentioned here is not active anymore. Do you know where they moved it to? I cannot find another PUN Oculus Avatar tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got your feedback and the tutorial will be reviewed and updated based on this.

To help you with your issue and answer your question:

The NetworkManager you need in this case and following the tutorials in whole needs to implement two PUN2 callbacks: `IMatchmakingCallbacks.OnJoinedRoom` and `IOnEventCallback.OnEvent`. While the tutorial may suggest that there could be two separate classes one implementing each callback (`NetworkManager` and `MyClass`), there is nothing against grouping them in one place.
In the tutorial's "Instantiating Avatars" section's first code block, we see that the `OnJoinedRoom` method is overridden. This probably means that the original writer assumed that the NetworkManager must be extending `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` class.
Inheriting from `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` class is the easiest and fastest way to implement PUN2 callbacks: it's a `MonoBehaviour` that allows you to selectively override the callbacks you need and only those you need, it already handles callbacks registration and deregistration on your behalf (respectively in `OnEnable` and `OnDisable`) it does not require having to remember all the callbacks' interfaces and it also extends `MonoBehaviourPun` which exposes the `PhotonView` easily in a property if the latter is attached to the same GameObject. However, you should be careful as it does not implement all callbacks interfaces but most. It implements `IConnectionCallbacks`, `IMatchmakingCallbacks`, `IInRoomCallbacks`, `ILobbyCallbacks` and `IWebRpcCallback`. It does not implement `IOnEventCallback`, `IPunInstantiateMagicCallback`, `IPunObservable` and `IPunOwnershipCallbacks`. PUN2's utility interfaces are also not implemented e.g. `IPunTurnManagerCallbacks`.

Talk is cheap, show me the code:

```
public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour, IMatchmakingCallbacks, IOnEventCallback
{
    public const byte InstantiateVrAvatarEventCode = 1;

    public void OnJoinedRoom() // w/o override
    {
        // code from the tutorial here
    }

    public void OnEvent(EventData photonEvent)
    {
        // code from the tutorial here
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.RemoveCallbackTarget(this);
    }

    #region Unused IMatchmakingCallbacks

    public void OnFriendListUpdate(List<FriendInfo> friendList)
    {
    }

    public void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
    }

    public void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
    }

    public void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
    }

    public void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
    }

    public void OnLeftRoom()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was about to update the question with the link to the tutorial which explain how to setup the whole thing (https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/lobby). It's my understanding you work for Photon, in this case I would kindly ask you to create a tutorial specifically for VR projects with Unity. Including manipulating grabbable rigid bodies in a room while keeping everything in sync. Your documentation is great but sometimes feels a bit too advanced. A step-by-step document accessible to all levels would be perfect!

Comment: OK. I will forward your request for a step-by-step guide for doing VR with PUN to the right team. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hey @JohnTube, the link to the tutorial mentioned in the question is not active anymore. Do you know where they moved it to? I cannot find another PUN Oculus Avatar tutorial.

Comment: Unfortunately the tutorial is not available anymore. I hope you can find some other tutorial online.